# c# Add a virtual printer that open a wpf program?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, dll, virtual-printer

I've searched for a solution for my problem but I can't really find one.

My problem is that I want to use a program I've written (wpf windows app) as a virtual printer.

The program usees the commandLineArgs and is processing the file.

The purpose of the driver is not for my personnal use, it's for companies, that is why I am searching for a simple solution for the client (even if it's a system admin or a developer).

I already have the installer for my application, all I need is a script file, or another code that can "install" a virtual driver

so  ->

**PDF FILE -> "print" -> MyProgram**

and, if possible, a script that installs my project as a virtual printer

I've already tried to use the opensource **Printer++** by creating a `DLL` that open my program,  but it does not work. I've followed the tutorial(s), but the *class library* never showed in the printer list.

Comment: Interesting. I'll wait to answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [Win2PDF](http://www.win2pdf.com) printer driver can automatically execute an application after it has processed a file.  Information on configuring this is at:

http://www.win2pdf.com/doc/automaticallyexecutinganapp.htm

By default, Win2PDF will pop up a file save window when you send a document to the printer driver, but you can disable the pop up by using the [Auto-name](http://www.win2pdf.com/doc/index.html?automatically-name-pdf.htm) feature.  You would probably want to configure Auto-name to only use the document title.